# Вопрос по Telegram API

Tags: php, api, telegram

Есть приватный канал, в котором числиться мой основной телеграм аккаунт, я хочу сделать пересылку сообщений из этого канала, в другой канал, каким образом это можно осуществить?

Comment: Что значит "числиться"? Вы владелец этого канала?

Comment: Нет, будь я владельцем этого канала, я бы не задавал сюда такие вопросы, есть чужой приватный канал, нужно с него по API получать сообщения, это реализуемо?

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#what-messages-will-my-bot-get

Comment: там написано, что вроде как бот может получать сообщения с каналов, в которых он зарегистрирован.

Comment: дальше идите в [документацию](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) Получайте нужный канал, получайте сообщения из него, и отправляйте в свой.

Comment: Канал закрытый, доступ только по добавлению администрации, доступ только с моего аккаунта, добавить туда бота я не смогу

Comment: в таком случае никак (насколько мне известно). В любом случае читайте документацию - там все написано.